# Java nested nested class

Tags: java

I'm curious how (if?) nested nested classes are supposed to work.

Eclipse Oxygen.3 didn't mention "Object Teams" however I assume the following code exemplifies some anti-pattern since I don't see a business need for a nested nested class.

```
public class CACCIData {
...
    public CompanySearchResultsResult.CompanySearchResult mcCompanySearchResult = null;

    public static class CompanySearchResultsResult {
        public List<CompanySearchResult> CompanySearchResult 
            = new ArrayList<CompanySearchResult>();

        public static class CompanySearchResult {
// ...
        }
    }
```

Eclipse 2018-12 compile error: `'CACCIData$CompanySearchResultsResult' cannot be used as type anchor for an externalized role: is not a team (OTJLD 1.2.2(b)).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Double-nested classes are syntactically valid.** The code below works and prints the logical, predictable output:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A().testPrintA();
    }
    public static class A {
        public void testPrintA() {
            System.out.println("Works from A.");
            new B().testPrintB();
        }
        public static class B {
            public void testPrintB() {System.out.println("Works from B.");}
        }
    }
}
```

*Now on the "should you use it" side... It is opinionated, but I believe there won't be too many opportunities where this construct offers the best solution.*